# Conditional column value in UI5 table

Tags: sapui5

I have a column in table whose value is bound to a property of data model. 
`text = { modelName>/OrderNo}`. How to make it conditional based on a flag? If property from Model `isReturnable = true`,  I want to show `text = {modelName>/ReturnNo}`  else I want to show `{OrderNo}`. How to built syntax for that?

```
<table:Column>
<Label class="smartist-table-column-header" text="Qty Returned"/>
<table:template>
<Text text="{ path: 'OrderDetail>OrderNo'}"/>
</table:template>
</table:Column>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *expression binding*.
See URL for details: https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0

Solution to your problem:

```
<Text text="{= ${modelName>isReturnable} ? ${modelName>/ReturnNo} : ${OrderDetail>OrderNo}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As expression binding would be a more appropriate approach to this problem,
Custom formatting can also be one way to achieve this.

In the view:

```
<Text text= "{      parts:[
                        {path: "modelName>isReturnable"},
                        {path: "modelName>ReturnNo"},
                        {path: "modelName>OrderNo"}, 

                     ],                        

                    formatter: '.formatOrderNo'
            }"/>
```

In the corresponding controller

```
formatter: function(isReturnable, sReturnNo, sOrderNo){ 

       if(isReturnable == true){
           return sReturnNo;
       }else{
           return OrderNo;
       }

}
```

In case of more complex logic where you need to perform some calculations/manipulations on the fields before binding, custom formatting is the way to go. [Custom Formatters in SAPUI5](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de)